# Prefetch data on Splash

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am trying to implement a feed app. I want to make the network call for new feed on Splash Activity which will run for a maximum of 3 seconds (irrespective of feed network call gets completed or not) and then move to my home screen where feed is visible to the user. I want the response of the call i made in Splash to be returned to my Home activity. I am using Retrofit with RxJava to make network calls. I have tried to use ConnectableObserver with replay operator to try this, but it is not working.

In SplashActivity's onCreate i call a method

> MyClientNetworkUtil.initObservable();

The MyClientNetworkUtil class has following code

> public class MyClientNetworkUtil {
>
> ```
> private static MyClient client = ServiceGenerator.generateService(MyClient.class);
>
> private static ConnectableObservable<List<DataModel>> x;
>
> public static void initObservable() {
>     Observable<List<DataModel>> o = client.dataForUser("user");
>     x = o.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).publish();
>     x.connect();
> }
>
> public static ConnectableObservable<List<DataModel>> getObservable() {
>     return x.replay(1);
> }
> ```
>
> }

Then in my HomeActivity's onCreate function, i am trying to do :

> ```
> ConnectableObservable<List<DataModel>> x = MyClientNetworkUtil.getObservable();
> x.connect();
> x.subscribe(response -> Log.d("Response", response.get(1).getName()), e -> Log.e("Response", e.toString()));
> ```

But none of the above log statements are executed.
Can you please help with what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: x.replay(1) means you get a different ConnentableObservable other than X.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake of using `ConnectableObservable`.

> `connect` method instructs it to begin begin emitting the items from
>   its underlying  Observable to its Subscriber.

So you should `subscribe` first and then `connect`.

This code will work:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    initObservable();
    getObservable().forEach(System.out::println);
    x.connect();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }

  private static ConnectableObservable<List<Integer>> x;

  public static void initObservable() {
    Observable<List<Integer>> o = Observable.range(1, 50).buffer(10);
    x = o.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).publish();
    // x.connect();
  }

  public static Observable<List<Integer>> getObservable() {
    return x.replay(1).refCount();
  }
```

But we have better way than `connect`. We can use `refCount` or `autoConnect`.

`refCount`

> Returns an `Observable` that stays connected to this `ConnectableObservable` as long as there is at least one subscription to this `ConnectableObservable`.

`autoConnect`

> Returns an `Observable` that automatically connects to this
>   `ConnectableObservable` when the first Subscriber subscribes.

Comment: You don't need to publish again via replay(1). Just x = o.replay(1).whateverConnectionYouNeed() could be fine.